# Django debug-toolbar wildly inaccurate summary results

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

I am using django debug-toolbar on django 1.4. The problem is, it gives me incorrect summary results.

For example, on a landing page which produces one query (check to see if the user is logged in). DT says that there are 43 queries taking 17.27ms. However, when I actually click the SQL queries tab, it does show the correct result -- 1 query in 0.47ms.

Is DT incompatible with 1.4 or something, or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Do you use toolbar from Pypi or from trunk? If from Pypi, try to install from trunk, maybe they already fix this

Comment: @neoascetic I did `$ sudo pip install django-debug-toolbar`. How/where do I install from trunk?

Comment: Run `sudo pip install git+git://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar.git`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was a known issue according to github. I recently had exactly the same problem.

https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/issues/88

I managed to resolve the issue by simply updating the django-toolbar to the latest version.